# magento add to cart button working but with broken link icon, why?

Tags: php, magento, checkout

on a product page on magento, my Add to Cart button works but shows the red 'no' icon when clicked and I dont know why. On my dev environment I've removed all custom theme edits, gone back to default theme (so should be as installed) yet I still get 'no' link icon when I click add to cart, or update cart from update cart page. Its very off putting for potential buyers. I'd added gzip code to .htaccess file but since replaced with old as per installation file.

See live version with problem here http://baabox.com/fitwatch.html

HTML tags seem to be in order, maybe a javascript problem? its driving me nuts for over a day now!

Comment: I don't know if it helps you, but what you want to be looking for, is why when clicked the state `disabled=""` is being added to the HTML markup. That's all that's happening.

Comment: Isn't your cookies? Here work fine.

Comment: the link works fine, its the broken link icon once clicked I need to get rid of. I've two magento installations with now the same theme, without modification, and one shows broken link icon and the other does not. I'm stumped! I've check js code around 'button.disabled' on each page and its identical. Could something in admin configuration do this? it is some kind of js JQuery conflict?

Comment: That is not a broken link icon, That is a icon to disable that button.. I think it will prevent the double click. that icon you can find in `yourmagentodirectory\js\extjs\resources\images\default\dd\' and css code is here in `yourmagentodirectory\js\extjs\css\dd.css' in line no 53. Then that class is used here in `yourmagentodirectory\js\extjs\ext-tree.js` to map with the button click I think.

Comment: thanks Girish, but it does not normally appear on magento sites. For some reason its showing on mine and I need to get rid of it as its off putting to people trying to buy and seeing it. its only just appeared and I've rolled back all edits to default installation on dev environment and it wont go away!

Comment: You want to remove that right. You comment the line no 53 in `yourmagentodirectory\js\extjs\css\dd.css` - this line `.x-dd-drop-nodrop .x-dd-drop-icon{
  background-image: url(../images/default/dd/drop-no.gif);
}` and try

Comment: thanks Girish SH. I've comment out that code, even deleted the image but its still showing. the image is also in js\extjs\resources\images\default\tree incase other css is pulling onto the product page, which I've deleted too. Cleared magento and browser caches. I'd like to understand why its showing in the first place, as it shouldnt be. It does not show on another magento installation I have, whilst commenting out CSS may work (its not at the moment!), not sure its the best solution

Answer (score 0):

in the css file the class button.disabled is generating this appearance. To change it i commented out the background grey colour and changed cursor property from 'not-allowed' to 'progress'

```
.button.disabled,
.button:disabled {
opacity: 0.6;
cursor: progress;
/* background: #C8C8C8; */
}
```

its just my personal preference for this appearance as it seems magento intended the button to show 'no link' icon, i think its off putting for the customer